# Get stdout from a pipe exec in an other program

Tags: c++, pipe, stdout, stdin

Im trying to catch the stdout of a program I compile like this `./prog | ./otherprog`

When I print in stdout from `prog`, my `otherprog` return me a code like `200:OK` in its stdout

How do I catch this code ?

I tried to `fgets` the stdin from `prog` but it doesnt fill up stdin

Comment: If this is unix and you are forking & execing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610781/implementing-pipe-and-redirection-together-in-c/50611612

Comment: Im not forking nor execing, they are two independent programs that just write to their stdout, I just want to catch the stdout of otherprog in prog

Comment: @loic.k - If you want `prog` to both provide input to `otherprog` and consume its output, you'll have to `fork`, manipulate file handles appropriately, then `exec`.

Comment: @StephenNewell I'll go that way, thank you